# Как игнорировать движение мыши влево вправо с зажатым колесиком?

Tags: javascript

Как игнорировать движение мыши влево вправо с зажатым колесиком (горизонтальный скролл) и в тоже время разрешить движение вверх вниз с зажатым колесиком(вертикальный скролл)

Comment: вы не можете устанавливать координаты мыши, следовательно и запретить ее движение тоже не можете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю такое простое решение. При нём вообще невозможно сдвинуться в блоке в стороны.

```js
$(function() {
  var l = 0;
  $('div').mousedown(function() {
    l = $(this).scrollLeft();
  });
  $('div').scroll(function(e) {
    $(this).scrollLeft(l);
  });
});
```

```css
div {width:150px;height:150px;overflow:auto}
span {display:block;width:1000px;height:1000px;background-color:#000}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><span></span></div>
```